# Load some alias just after SSH login

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, ssh, alias

In my daily work I often need to use a ssh connection on a device (which you can consider as read only), and the commands I write are long.

That's why I would like to load some alias just after ssh login.
But when I try something as follow, it don't works:

ssh name@ipAdress "bash -l ; alias short='veryLongCommandThatIWriteOften'"

I guess that's because bash stop the processing of the other commands which are just after.

**So is it possible to set aliases directly as an argument of bash, or is there another solution to do what I want?**

Comment: Why not set the alias once login?

Comment: Because it would be longer than just write the command. (There is several long command actually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an alias, you can use a shell function, which `bash` allows you to export. This way, you first define the function, then export its name, and finally start a *new* interactive shell which inherits your function. For example:

```
ssh -t name@ipAddress "short () { veryLongCommandThatIWriteOften; }; export -f short; bash"
```

The `-t` is necessary to set up the pseudo terminal for the interactive `bash` shell, as `ssh` won't do it automatically for an apparently non-interactive command.

Note that you many need to be careful about quoting, depending on what the body of `short` is.

Comment: Thank you! This will save me a lot of time :)
But last question, if I want to give an argument to that function, I tried something like:

short ($1) { veryLongCmd $1 ; }; export -f short; bash

But it don't work, what do I do wrong? :/

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file ~/.bashrc

nano ~/.bashrc

It has examples of how to set aliases also. Log back in to have new alias work.

Comment: As I wrote before, the device is in Read Only mode. So modifying the .bashrc or something like this is not possible.